# View connection messages

Tags: ubuntu, networking, internet, tcpip

I'm investigating some bugs on a Android Application, that uses a Third-party plugin.
I need to view all connections messages between this plugin and a server. There is some way to list all send packages from a device in my network to a specific server?

Answer (score 1):

you could use [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to monitor all network traffic

Follow these [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555403/capturing-mobile-phone-traffic-on-wireshark) from stackoverflow

Comment: Can you expand on this? Maybe describe the steps he needs to take to get Wireshark running properly, explaining it's not a virus even though many AVs treat it as such, etc?